# Old School RuneScape magic training: finding best items for high level alchemy?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

In Old School RuneScape, High Level Alchemy is a spell which converts items into money. How can I figure out the best items on which to cast this spell if I want to gain Magic experience? Here, "best" means a combination of low loss per cast (self-explanatory), low unit cost per item (so I can buy a lot of casts' worth of supplies at once), and generous four-hour Grand Exchange buy limit (same reason).

([This answer to a similar question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/73708/132872) provides an answer for standard RuneScape, i.e. RuneScape 3, in the form of a dynamically-updating website which lists the necessary information.)

Answer (score 1):

**[This spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SlxbHJokMGsPGqIHcY4SXvzouuYdbZ8TYHYCbFRTWXA/)** contains an up-to-date (Jan 2016) high alchemy calculator using OSBuddy price data. Here's some information from the [reddit announcement thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/2007scape/comments/401tml/updated_osrs_automatic_spreadsheets_farming/):

> Prices automatically refresh every 2 hours or upon my manual request. Check the Welcome page for when the prices were updated.
>
> [The] High Alch page... compares the alch price and OSB selling (higher) price of all items in the game. It is sortable by alch profit, which includes the price of a nature rune. Most of the items on the top are low trade volume (easily manipulated prices), but there are usually some good ones there.

Note that this spreadsheet depends on OSBuddy's price data, so it might break occasionally when OSBuddy is undergoing maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few places that can do this for you.

- [GE Tracker](https://www.ge-tracker.com/) (My recommendation)
- [Scape XP](http://www.scape-xp.com/runescape-high-alchemy.html)
- [The previously mentioned spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SlxbHJokMGsPGqIHcY4SXvzouuYdbZ8TYHYCbFRTWXA/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. GE Tracker looks cool, but it seems it's  a paid service - any affiliation with them? Also, Scape XP's old school prices are broken, sadly (I think they might pull from the Zybez price guide).